# Asynchronuos callback saves value but prints FAILED

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

I am using nested Asynchronous callbacks to save my front-end data to the back-end database. The data is being save into the tables the way i want them to, but it is printing that it failed. Here is the code:

```
    if(erasync == null)
        erasync = GWT.create(EntityRelationService.class);
    AsyncCallback<Void> callback = new AsyncCallback<Void>(){
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            String msg = caught.getLocalizedMessage();
             if (caught instanceof NotFoundException) {
                msg = ((NotFoundException) caught).getType()
                      + ((NotFoundException) caught).getMessage();
             }
           System.out.println("Failed" + msg);
        }
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    if(erasync == null)
                        erasync = GWT.create(EntityRelationService.class);
                    AsyncCallback<Void> callbackOthers = new AsyncCallback<Void>(){
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                            String msg = caught.getLocalizedMessage();
                             if (caught instanceof NotFoundException) {
                                msg = ((NotFoundException) caught).getType()
                                      + ((NotFoundException) caught).getMessage();
                             }
                           System.out.println("Failed" + msg);
caught.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                            System.out.println("Success");
                        }                           
                    };
                    erasync.setEntityType(name, top, left, pname, callbackOthers);
        };
        erasync.setProject(name, callback);
```

Here it prints successful for the first callback, but for the nested one it says failed though it saves the value. Here is the stack that it prints for failure:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:192)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessages(BrowserChannel.java:1668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:401)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Am i missing something?

Any input will be of great help.
Thank you.

Comment: Please post, what it prints exactly: "Failed..."

Comment: It might be helpful to restructure your code to include fewer inline anonymous classes (callbacks, clickhandlers). Making your code more readable means more people will be able to answer your question, and you may even discover a bug while refactoring.

Comment: I tried to print the error stack but it is just printing failed(this is the println statement in failure method of asynchronous method). I am not sure why it is entering the Failure method.

Comment: Try harder :) Add a breakpoint in the nested onFailure method and see what that `Throwable` is.

Comment: I'm not too much surprised, that it prints nothing given the code in the onFailure method. Add a little `caught.printStackTrace()` in the line below your `System.out.println("Failed" + msg);` - and it will print something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I solved the problem. I was having this problem because the window was reloading and changing the status code when there were still asynchronous calls in process. I included the window reload at the end of my method and its working fine now. Thanks all.